# convert string date(yyyy/mm/dd) to date format in db2

Tags: db2

I am saving the date as varchar in db2 with `yyyy/mm/dd` format i need to convert it to date datetype in the query how to achieve this?

I tried

> select DATE(CRDTR2) from ASAODLIB.SSLR204 where CRDTR2 BETWEEN
>   '2015/03/01' AND '2015/03/31';

query and got the below error

> The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is
>   incorrect.. SQLCODE=-180, SQLSTATE=22007, DRIVER=3.68.61

can someone help me.

Comment: What platform and version of DB2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your DB2 version is new enough, use to_date: `select DATE(TO_DATE(CRDTR2, 'YYYY/MM/DD')) from ...`

Comment: Thank you.this works for me. will it also work in db2 v8.1 as well? currently am using 10.1

Answer (score 1):

...because it doesn't recognize that format.  I'd turn it into `*ISO` first, via [`REPLACE`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000843.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-122&lang=en):

```
SELECT DATE(REPLACE(CRDTR2, '/', '-'))
FROM ASAODLIB.SSLR204 
WHERE CRDTR2 BETWEEN '2015/03/01' AND '2015/03/31'
```

---

Incidentally, there's a couple other things here.

1. You should be storing dates as an actual date type, which would make this a non-issue.
2. [You shouldn't use `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), in preference for an exclusive upper-bound (`<` - the blog talks about SQL Server, but the problem is really due to representation.  That, and most versions of DB2 allow you to specify fractional seconds in timestamps...).